# Cannot set up Zyxel NWA55AXE as wireless repeater

Tags: wireless-networking, repeater

I have chosen this device because I need a cheap wireless **outdoor** repeater for private use.
I want to use the device as wireless repeater. It receives the W-LAN signal from the router and sends out a W-LAN network using the same name and password.
I connected the device using a LAN cable to my router. I do this only for configuration. Later I want to remove the cable.
First I tried the Zyxel Nebula Android app but it has almost no settings. So I went to my PC and opened the web interface.

I have switched the first radio module (2,4GHz) to repeater mode. It is strange that the 5GHz module cannot be switched to repeater mode.

I have set up a WDS uplink but the status is always gray and never switches to yellow.

What is wrong here?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the support request :
[Is it possible to operate a Zyxel NWA55AXE AP as a Wifi repeater without a second Zyxel device ?](https://community.zyxel.com/en/discussion/13765/is-it-possible-to-operate-a-zyxel-nwa55axe-ap-as-a-wifi-repeater-without-a-second-zyxel-device)

Question :

> I would like to operate the Zyxel NWA55AXE AP only as a repeater,
> purely via Wifi (without LAN) with a Telekom router without a second
> Zyxel device is that possible?
>
> Or do I need a second Zyxel device connected to LAN as a bridge?

Answer :

> Sorry, we don’t support connecting another brand AP via wireless. You
> need a second Zyxel AP as a root AP to connect NWA55AXE and LAN.

It seems like what you're asking is impossible, because your router
is not from Zyxel and because your device is not an AP.

Conclusion : This Zyxel device seems unsuitable for your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options still:

1. Install openwrt on your zyxel NWA55AXE and then configure a client connection that is repeated.

Firmware: https://openwrt.org/toh/hwdata/zyxel/zyxel_nwa55axe

Guide to configuration of repeater mode: https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/network/wifi/relay_configuration

2. (I have not tested this option) Install openwrt on your main wifi router and create a WDS bridge and then configure your Zyxel NWA55AXE to use a custom WDS profile for it's repeater-mode.

WDS Setup: https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/network/wifi/atheroswds

Zyxel WDS Setup: https://mysupport.zyxel.com/hc/en-us/articles/360008419199--AP-How-to-set-up-a-WDS-Wireless-Distribution-System-link-between-pro-wireless-access-points-firmware-5-10-and-newer-

I personally purchased two of these Zyxel NWA55AXE outdoor devices to use one as the anchor wired into my network and the other as a repeater. I was unable to get this configuration working using stock firmware in standalone mode and configuring one as Root-AP and the other as Repeater based on the guide: https://support.zyxel.eu/hc/en-us/articles/360006093259-WDS-setup-between-standalone-APs. The WDS bridge connected wirelessly but then no clients from the wireless/repeater side would get connectivity back over the wireless bridge. Client on the root-ap side worked fine but clients on the repeater side would not get internet access.

To resolve my configuration which is nearly identical to your own, I flashed both NWA55AXE's with openwrt and manually setup the bridge and connections without WDS and everything was fine. (not saying WDS was an issue; it was just more complex than needed for my use-case)

My config:

Main Router(DHCP|Firewall|NAT)<--->Zyxel NWA55AXE (Root-ap) ((((-----)))) Zyxel NWA55AXE (Repeater) (((-----))) Clients very far away

I'm sure I could have opened a support ticket requesting assistance for why the bridge works but no connectivity over it and provided logs, but I didn't have the luxury of time and needed to get these devices working ASAP. In theory the two devices on stock firmware should be sufficient(marketed as such) but in this scenario it was not and could be potentially resolved in a future firmware update since these are relatively new units.

If you haven't returned it already, these are great units for the price once you flash them to openwrt.

Lastly:

> I have switched the first radio module (2,4GHz) to repeater mode. It is strange that the 5GHz module cannot be switched to repeater mode.

The device works with either 2.4GHz as the client or 5GHz, so it works for me creating the WDS uplink over both, once the other Root-AP side was set on the right frequency. I personally would rather that they had both frequencies using whichever was the ideal at the time but based on the WDS openwrt configuration it's apparent why it's tied to the specific radio interface because configuring both just creates two paths and a network loop. (these devices are waiting for software to catch up)